# Is there a font family that contains all characters listed on the groff_char page?

Tags: fonts

I am looking for a font family that contains all the characters listed on this pages:

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/groff_char.7.html

Id est mainly latin 1, greek letters and mathematical characters.
I am only using bold and italic (not bold-italic), is there ant font that meets those criteria?

Comment: There are plenty of fonts that should contain all the glyphs mentioned on that page – they’re pretty standard glyphs. Some of the fractional glyphs may have been left out in some otherwise usable fonts, but many also have them. Times New Roman, Georgia, Adobe Garamond/Text/Jenson, etc., should all provide what you’re looking for.

Comment: If you took closely, there are symbols like "right brace extension", "therefore" and "h bar" that aren't part of those fonts (at least the versions I checked)

Comment: You could roll your own font with Font Forge if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Noto is the most likely, but I don't know of a good tool to input a list of characters and check a font can display them.

Edit: another likely choice if you want a serif: STIX Two for mathematical publishing. Has four weights and is free.

Comment: All the character I checked are available in bold, but not in roman, that's a bit weird but thank you for the suggestion

Comment: I'd be surprised by that, since the regular weight should have all the characters. Might be worth checking you got an up-to-date version just of "Noto Sans" or "Noto Serif" from Google. But I have thought of another better choice if you want a serif: STIX Two. It's created for mathematical publishing.

Comment: I am using the version distributed on fonts.google.com, I was also surprised! I will check STIX, it was my first thought but for some reason I did not check it, thanks